# how to conditionally ignore cell when applying sumproduct using Numbers (Mac)

Tags: numbers

Under Excel, there's something like = Sumproduct((A1:A100),--(A1:A100<>"")) from Excel formula -> how to change SUMPRODUCT formula to skip null cells

But it did not work for Numbers. Wondering if there's a good way to achieve it using Numbers

E.g. I would like to do the sumproduct of following two columns, but only if the value of the second column is greater than 1

1   1

2   2

3   3

4   4

5   5

Comment: isn't the sum of zeros , zero !

Comment: I did not get your point, what did you mean.

Comment: turned out sumproduct will automatically exclude empty cell, then what if we would like to conditionally exclude cells for sumproduct?

Comment: did you end up founding a solution for this @cheneychen? I'm looking for the exact same solution: http://superuser.com/questions/971060/google-sheets-excel-sumproduct-but-ignore-empty-cells